# Drupal, copy values from a content to another content

Tags: drupal, copy, cck, drupal-fields

I've created two content types with CCK:

1. is a recipe with a multigroup field for ingredients;
2. is a shopping list.

the users can create many shopping lists. I would like to have a dropdown menu with all the user's shopping lists and an "add to shopping list" button near every ingredient to put the selected ingredient in the chosen list.

It may be also useful to do the same with the entire content. For example adding the whole recipe to a "menu" content...

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have knowledge in PHP to code? Can you not use an ecommerce module and modify it to suit ingredients?

Comment: I can code and I too had the idea of modifying a simple "cart" module. but I think there are *lots* of modification, both in the cart and in the content... and instead of this solution would be better to create a new module.

Comment: And with "shopping list" I just mean the list you carry with you when you go to the mall. So you cannot buy anything on the site I'm doing...

Comment: Maybe another way is to have a form as a cck field. So I could add the form after the ingredients. Being the form a field itself, it will be exposed viewing the node and the suer can submit it...

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the shopping list so that it has a nodereference field in that field you would reference the menu or menus, and then display the ingredients for the different menus in a view.